# Evaluating a matlab function in C# that requires a matrix input

Tags: c#, matlab, matrix

I made a function for a neural network I created inside matlab. I can successfully load the function in c#, but I don't know how I enter a matrix as the input as arrays don't work.

**Original Matlab function**

```
function energy = simCW(x)
%x is a 4xQ matrix (I always sim 4x1 though)
S = load('CW100', 'CB_CW100');
CB_CW100 = S.CB_CW100;
energy = sim(CB_CW100,x')'; 
end
```

**Matlab line for generation function for C#**

```
genFunction(CB_CW100, 'cbcw.m', 'MatrixOnly','yes', 'ShowLinks','no')
```

**Generated Function**

```
function [y1] = cbcw(x1)
%CBCW neural network simulation function.
% [y1] = cbcw(x1) takes these arguments:
%   x = 4xQ matrix, input #1
% and returns:
%   y = 1xQ matrix, output #1
% where Q is the number of samples.
```

**C# Code** - [Source](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
        double[] current = new double[4];
        current[0]= 71;
        current[1] = 74;
        current[2] = 8;
        current[3] = 105;
        matlab.Execute("cbcw");
        object result = null;
        matlab.Feval("cbcw", 1, out result, current);
        object[] res = result as object[];
        Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

The running the program is opening a matlab command line and writing the following to the console:

```
System.Double[,]
```

I want a number written to the console, without opening matlab as this eventually will be a stand alone process for computers without matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to consider each element of your matrix as an input, and inside your matlab function you can organize these inputs argument to construct your matrix.

for example

matlab :

```
function [y1] = cbcw(x1,x2,x3,x4)
x=[x1 X2;x3 x4];
```

c# :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
        double[] current = new double[4];
        current[0]= 71;
        current[1] = 74;
        current[2] = 8;
        current[3] = 105;
        matlab.Execute("cbcw");
        object result = null;
        matlab.Feval("cbcw", 1, out result, current[0],current[1],current[2],current[3]);
        object[] res = result as object[];
        Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```